# Start and Stop SQL Server on my development laptop

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server Express on my laptop. I only need to hit it every few weeks. Running SQL Server sucks up a fair bit of memory on my laptop so I was wondering what is the easiest way to turn off SQL Server when not using it?

What I have done thus far is to create two batch files on my desktop. One brings SQL Server up with this command:

```
net start "sql server (sqlexpress)"
```

and the other takes it down with this:

```
net stop "sql server (sqlexpress)"
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? Maybe a tool try app or something other than batch files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The old SQL 2000 system tray service manager actually works with any service (just configure the service name). There is also a codeplex project for a 2005 replacement: http://www.codeplex.com/SQL2005SrvcMngr/

Comment: I thought I was remembering that there used to be a built in tool for doing this. Cool!

Answer (score 1):

I would move your shortcuts into your Quicklaunch bar :)

Or you could even use a tool like launchy to easily run the shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about installing SQL Server onto a virtual machine?  That way SQL Server doesn't need to be installed on your system and anytime you need it you just fire up the VM.

Comment: I had thought about that but was concerned about starting speed as well as hard drive requirements

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the prompting from some of the answered here, the best I have found is [Windows Service Manager Tray](http://winservicemanager.codeplex.com/) because it also allows me to start and stop other services, not just SQL Server. it lives in the tray and is easy to config/use.

Thanks Remus Rusanu for pointing me toward the idea of a general service manager. I had been thinking only about something SQL Server specific.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually written my own system tray app that reads a folder for short cuts or batch files. It gives me very quick access to my scripts.

You could also create a start menu option and/or use something like [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/) to quickly run you scripts.

Comment: launchy makes sense. You and skippyfire both recommended that. I'll have to check it out

Answer (score -1):

Control Panel>Administrative Tools>Services

Find MSSQL service and disable it or put it to start on manual request.

Comment: yes indeed. But then I would have to do a bunch of clicks to restart it. That is less elegant than my current batch file approach.

Answer (score -1):

I guess I can't see what could be easier than clicking to start a batch file or clicking a button in the service manager sys tray app.